# Document click not in elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery how does one detect clicks not on specific elements, and perform an action consequently?

I have the following JavaScript

```
$('#master').click(function() {
    $('#slave').toggle();
});

$(document).not('#master','#slave').click(function() {
    $('#slave').hide();
});
```

and I cannot see where I am going wrong logically. You can see a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ4Hz/1/)

Comment: binding an instance of your click handler to every DOM element (except two) is going to be awful on performance.

Comment: The reason why your version doesn't work is because you're testing whether the `document` element doesn't have `master` or `slave` as its ID. This is always true (IIRC `document` can't have an ID), so the handler is bound to the `document` and every click will cause `slave` to be hidden. Then, because of event propagation, the `click` event from `#master` will bubble up to the `document` where it will hide `#slave`, even though `#master` just toggled it. You need to test `event.target` to make this work.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Since you're binding to the `click` event on the document, you can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to get the element that initiated the event:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is("#master, #slave")) {
        $("#slave").hide();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** As Mattias rightfully points out in his comment, the code above will fail to identify click events coming from descendants of `#master` and `#slave` (if there are any). In this situation, you can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to check the event's target:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest("#master, #slave").length) {
        $("#slave").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: If `#master` or `#slave` have child elements, you need to use `closest` instead of `is` to make it work on those children.

Comment: This is a poor substitute for [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) which is already implemented in jQuery.

Comment: @zzzzBov, not really, the goal here is to delegate all the `click` events to the document and to special-case two elements and their descendants. Are you sure you can achieve the same thing with `delegate()` (or rather `on()`, which supersedes it in recent releases)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, easily, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Does this code do what you want? (not entirely sure if I understood correctly)

```
$('body').on('click', '*:not( #master, #slave )', function() {
    $('#slave').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gZ4Hz/8/

Answer (score 2):

Event delegation has long been supported natively by jQuery. The difficulty lies in creating the appropriate selector. Originally, [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) was used, but more recently the delegate form of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) should be used.

The purpose of event delegation is to listen to events on child elements and invoke the bound event handlers on those elements as though they had been bound to the child element, instead of the parent. This means that instead of binding handlers to *every* element in the DOM, you're binding a handler to every element in the initial selection (`document` is a single element). This also makes for a simple way to use a single selector to bind to an ever changing set of elements, as new elements will propagate their events to `document` whether or not they existed when the initial event handler was bound:

```
$(document).on('click', '*:not(#master, #master *, #slave, #slave *)', function (e) {
    //this will reference the clicked element
});
```

Additionally, note that I not only said the elements must not be `#master` or `#slave`, they **must not** be children of `#master` or `#slave` either.

Comment: Very interesting. I usually avoid `*` selectors both in CSS (cascading is sufficient most of the time) and in jQuery (matching a whole subtree can be costly), but I agree this should work at least as well as `event.target` combined to `closest()` on modern browsers. Now I'm curious about the perfs, maybe I'll set up a benchmark in my copious free time. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Another thought, it may not be working because your browser may not be rendering `body` at 100% height; Try adjusting your base css to fix height of body and then a couple other thoughts.

[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/): *Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.*

So if you change the first click code to the following:

```
$('#master').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#slave').toggle();
});
```

Then you could change the call sign of the second too:

```
$("body, body *").not('#master, #slave').click(function(e) {
    $('#slave').hide();
});
```

And that should cover it. Give it a try! or see [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/e6sFy/)

Comment: Binding event handlers to every other elements isn't a good idea. Frédéric Hamidi's solution is better.

Comment: That is a horrible solution. You're binding that second handler separately to **every single element in the DOM**. Not only is this terribly inefficient, it won't even work with dynamically inserted elements added to the DOM afterwards. Frédéric's solution is much more elegant and (more importantly) works in every situation.

Comment: I never said it was the best solution and it's not "horrible". I simply showed him how to achieve what he was trying to achieve. So many "professors" on here. lmao

Answer (score 0):

Fredrik's answers works for elements already present in the document, but it didn't work for elements fetched by ajax calls.
I tried the following and it works for me. Sharing the code for future ajax coders.

```
    $(document).on('click',function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest("#selector").length) {
            if ($('#selector').is(":visible"))
                $('#selector').slideUp();
        }
    });
```

Would have posted it as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clickable-row').on("click",function(){
  window.location = $(this).data('href');
  return false;
});
$("td > a").on("click",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.clickable-row').on("click",function(){
      window.location = $(this).data('href');
      return false;
    });
    $("td > a").on("click",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```