# jquery slide down div on link click, then slide up when clicking outside of div

Tags: jquery

Anyone know how I can have a link which when clicked slides down a div, then the div slides back up when anywhere outside the div is clicked ?

Thnx in advance.

Scott.

Comment: Please post some code, ideally a link to the problem on jsfiddle.net to help us to help you.

Comment: @Davo Please don't link to W3Schools. A lot of the information on there is outdated and/or incorrect. http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".clicker").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do your worst, i.e. slide down
    $("div").slideDown("slow");
});

$(document).click(function() {
    // slide up
    $("div").slideUp("slow");
});
```

And just to make sure the div is not affected either:

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: sorry for being stupid but how do i format my link, its a standard link for a search box. Do i have it like this : <li><a id="slider"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>

Comment: It's up to you how you format things, in this script $(".clicker") is the link that slides down the $("div"). You can change these to anything, it could be a $("li a"), or a $("#slider"). Entirely up to you. The logic remains the same.

Comment: ok thanks so if my link looks like this : <li><a id="slider"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li> i would use $(".slider").click(function(e) is that right ? thanks again for your help.

Comment: If it's id of "slider" then use $("#slider"), for class of "slider" use $(".slider"), for all anchors that happen to be in a list item use $("li a"). Hope that helps. (For more on jquery selectors see here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ )

Comment: ok sorry for being confusing but what would i put for a specific link thats in a li, do i need to use "li a" or will #slider still be ok ?

Comment: If you want the click functionality on just one anchor then use id, $("#slider") or $("a#slider"). Using "li a" would attach the click event to all anchors that are in a li. Documentation covers selectors pretty well.

Comment: ok great thanks. When i click the link its refeshing the page for some reason. Any ideas ?

Comment: My best guess is that you haven't used the code above. Especially the e.preventDefault() line. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rq4Vm/1/ Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".target").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".class").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a very good answer by Frederik in [Document click not in elements jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851312/document-click-not-in-elements-jquery/10851375#10851375)

Modified a bit to support elements not yet present in document for example elements fetched by ajax calls.

```
$(document).on('click',function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest("#selector").length) {
        if ($('#selector').is(":visible"))
            $('#selector').slideUp();
    }
});
```