# div slideDown on button click and div slideUp on click outside

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

issue is that the function which slides menu up on click outside executes right after one which slides menu down on trigger click(so on click menu slides down and then slides up right away) and it shouldn't, it must execute after click outside, what is wrong with it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// build a variable to target the #menu div
var menu = $('#menu')
// bind a click function to the menu-trigger
$('#menu-trigger').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // if the menu is visible slide it up
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(400);
    }
    // otherwise, slide the menu down
    else
    {
        menu.slideDown(400);
    }
});     

$("body").not('#menu, #menu-trigger').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(400);
    }
});
```

})

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yGMZt/1/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete behavior you wanted

Use `$(document)` instead `$('body')`

```
$(document).not('#menu, #menu-trigger').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(400);
    }
});
```

#### Updated Fiddle

And also use `event.stopPropagation()` in `click()` of menu trigger

Answer (score 1):

Found a very good answer by Frederik in [Document click not in elements jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851312/document-click-not-in-elements-jquery/10851375#10851375)

Modified a bit to support elements not yet present in document for example elements fetched by ajax calls.

```
$(document).on('click',function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest("#selector").length) {
        if ($('#selector').is(":visible"))
            $('#selector').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `event.stopPropagation();` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruddog2003/yGMZt/3/)

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. 
>   [more](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

event.stopPropagation() to stop propagation default browser
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var expanded = false;
        // When clicked on the menu-trigger
        $("#menu-trigger").click(
            function(event) {
                // Slide down menu if hidden
                if (!expanded) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    $("#menu").slideDown();
                    expanded = true;
                }
                // Slide up menu if shown
                else {
                    $("#menu").slideUp();
                    expanded = false;
                }
            }
        );
        // Hide if clicked anywhere on the page
        $(document).click(
            function () {
                if (expanded) {
                    $("#menu").slideUp();
                    expanded = false;
                }
            }
        );
        // Prevent slideUp if clicked on the Menu div itself
        // (You can omit this part if you don't need it)
        $("#menu").click(
            function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        );
    }
);
```